# Integrating spherical harmonic function

Tags: calculus, harmonic-functions, spherical-coordinates, spherical-harmonics

How do you evaluate

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin \theta ~ Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi) \mathrm d\theta \mathrm d\phi $$

where $Y_{lm}(\theta, \phi)$ is the spherical harmonic defined as

$$Y_{lm} (\theta, \phi) = (-1)^{m} \sqrt{\frac{(2l + 1)}{4\pi}\frac{(l-m)!}{(l+m)!}} P_{lm}(\cos\theta) e^{i m\phi}$$

Comment: Use the fact that $Y^0_{0}=1/\sqrt{4\pi}$ and orthogonality of spherical harmonics:
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi \int_0^\pi d\theta\sin\theta \:Y^m_\ell(\theta, \phi)Y^{m'}_{\ell'}(\theta, \phi)=\delta_{\ell\ell'}\delta_{mm'}
$$
To obtain
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi \int_0^\pi d\theta\sin\theta \:Y^m_\ell(\theta, \phi)=\sqrt{4\pi}\delta_{\ell0}\delta_{m0}
$$

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for.